# The line with the equation $2x-3y=10$ touches the circle with center $M(-2,4)$ at point $A$. Find the equation of $A$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, systems-of-equations, circles

This is one of the last problems on my sheet but i can't seem to understand it. Several of my friends have tried explaining it to me but i still can't seem to get it, i think i need some new perspectives so i could better understand this problem ://

Comment: Assuming the circle and the line are tangent, then the radius is perpendicular to the line. In other words, find a line perpendicular to $2x - 3y = 10$ that passes through $(-2, 4)$.

Answer (score 3):

The essential point is that the line from the center of a circle to the point of contact of a tangent is perpendicular to the tangent.  Call this line L.  If we can find the equation of L, then we know that the point A lies on both L and the line $2x-3y=10$ so solving these equation simultaneously will give A.

We know the tangent has slope $\frac23$ so L has slope $-\frac32.$  The equation of L is of the form $y=-\frac32 x + b$.  Since we know that $(-2,4)$ lies on L, we can solve for $b$ to get the equation of L, then we can solve for A as described above.

Comment: you wanted to say $y=-\frac32x+b$

Comment: @farruhota Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Option:

1)$ (x+2)^2+ (y-4)^2=r^2.$

Differentiate with respect to $x:$

$2(x+2)+2(y-4)dy/dx =0$.

At point of tangency $A$:

$dy/dx= 2/3$ , slope of $2x-3y=10$.

Hence:

$2(x+2) +2(y-4)(2/3) =0$, or

$6(x+2) +4(y-4)=0$,

$6x+4y= 4.$

2)Tangent line : $2x-3y=10.$

Solve the simultaneous equations to find $A(x,y).$

Note:

Implicit differentiation yields:

$2(x+2)+2(y-4)m= 0$, where $dy/dx=m$, slope of the given line.

Hence

$(1/m)(x+2) +(y-4)=0, $

a straight line passing through the centre of the circle $M(-2,4)$ with slope $-(1/m)$.

Comment: what does $6x+4y=4$ represent? what do you get when you take implicit differentiation?

Comment: farruhota.Good question.Let me try: dy/dx,  the gradient of the tangent of the circle at points (x,y) on the circle.The given line is tangent to the circle , hence dy/dx = m, (x,y) of the circle is a point on the line.Your thoughts? Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, dy/dx is the slope of the tangent line, however, what happens when you plug this slope into the implicit differential? what line is it now? why should you consider it with the tangent line to find the tangent point?

Comment: I am not saying it is incorrect, in fact, it is correct, you do get the correct answer, +1. I just want to hear your interpretation.

Comment: farruhota. Say, let's solve for dy/dx =f(x,y), this gives the gradient of the tangent line at a point (x,y) on the circle.The point of tangency is a point on the line, i. e. satifies the equation of the line.In addition dy/dx is the slope Altogether I think the resulting eq. 6x+4y=4 is only(!) a second eq. to find (x,y). Could not interpret it otherwise. But along the lines of Saulspatz, m(perp)=-3/2, point M(-2,4), write a line with m through M, you get "my equation".Wrong?Your thoughts!

Comment: yes, it is a normal line, good luck

Comment: Thanks.Greetings, Peter

Comment: farruhota.Perhaps interpretation of the result of implicit differentiation is at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The method given by saulspatz is definitely easier!

Here is an alternative method: the [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) from the point $M(-2,4)$ to the tangent line $2x - 3y = 10$ is:
$$r=\frac{|2(-2)-3(4)-10|}{\sqrt{2^2+(-3)^2}}=\frac{26}{\sqrt{13}}=2\sqrt{13}.$$
The equation of a circle with center $M(-2,4)$ and the radius $2\sqrt{13}$ is:
$$(x+2)^2+(y-4)^2=52.$$
The tangent point $A$ is:
$$\begin{cases}2x - 3y = 10\\(x+2)^2+(y-4)^2=52\end{cases} \Rightarrow A(2,-2).$$